# Azure Logic Apps - Rehost viewer

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I need to rehost Azure Logic Apps Viewer.
I Need to host graphical editor in web page and set all task in read-only mode.
I need to set current status of workflow and color each step. For success steps, green, for error steps, red.

Comment: So you need to show the logic app designer in a web page ? just grant reader permission to your user on the logic app ?

Comment: Or push logs to log analytics and grant permission to your user to view logic app executions

Comment: I don't want to grant each user manually to my subscription and then grant Logic app permissions. I want to see read-only diagram and execution flow (like workflow foundation debugger). If rehost isn't possible, I must choise another product